# VB: Check if Object has “Class” then Execute Code

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio

I am looking to find something in Visual Basic that basically states that if something collides with something with a certain class, it executes code. I may not be using correct terms, so when I say object I mean like a label or picture box, and a class is... well like a class in HTML, I guess, like an object with a trait.

The pseudocode would look something like this:

```
If object.Bounds.IntersectsWith([object with certain class]) Then execute code
```

Otherwise, the game's 'if' statements will overwhelm... Also I am new to Visual Basic language, so please keep it as simple as possible.

Here is what I have already:

```
    If carblue.Bounds.IntersectsWith(boundary1.Bounds) And directiona = 1 Then
        directiona = 0
        carblue.Top += 2
    ElseIf carblue.Bounds.IntersectsWith(boundary1.Bounds) And directiona = 2 Then
        directiona = 0
        carblue.Left += 2
    ElseIf carblue.Bounds.IntersectsWith(boundary1.Bounds) And directiona = 3 Then
        directiona = 0
        carblue.Top -= 2
    ElseIf carblue.Bounds.IntersectsWith(boundary1.Bounds) And directiona = 4 Then
        directiona = 0
        carblue.Left -= 2
    End If
```

Where carblue is the object being controlled, boundary1 is the obstacle that stops the car from moving (on collision) and directiona is the value of the direction the car is travelling (1 is up, 2 is left, etc).

(Moved from S.A. Programmers site)

Answer (score 0):

Without actual sample code to work with, it's not easy to provide a specific solution. I don't know how many controls you have moving around, is it 2? 10? 10,000? Assuming you have 10+ controls moving around, this is how I would handle it.

I would use a datatable to keep a record of the Bounds for each Control that moves or is collidable. After a control moves, update that row in the datatable, look for collisions, then check the object types to determine what kind of class the collided object is, and then run the code as needed.

```
    Public MovingControls As DataTable

    Sub Main()
        'Build the DataTable
        MovingControls = New DataTable("ControlBounds")
        MovingControls.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
        MovingControls.Columns.Add("x1", GetType(Integer))
        MovingControls.Columns.Add("x2", GetType(Integer))
        MovingControls.Columns.Add("y1", GetType(Integer))
        MovingControls.Columns.Add("y2", GetType(Integer))
    End Sub

    'Call this only when a control/object is created
    Sub MovingControlAdded(sender As Control)
        Dim Row As DataRow = MovingControls.NewRow
        Row("Name") = sender.Name
        Dim BoundsRect As Drawing.Rectangle = sender.Bounds
        Row("x1") = sender.Bounds.Left
        Row("x2") = sender.Bounds.Right
        Row("y1") = sender.Bounds.Bottom
        Row("y2") = sender.Bounds.Top
        MovingControls.Rows.Add(Row)
    End Sub

    'Call this only when a control/object has moved
    Sub MovingControlMoved(sender As Control)
        'Update the location of this Control
        Dim Row() As DataRow = MovingControls.Select("Name = '" & sender.Name & "'")
        'Select returns an array of Rows but there should only be 1 row for each Control
        Row(0)("x1") = sender.Bounds.Left
        Row(0)("x2") = sender.Bounds.Right
        Row(0)("y1") = sender.Bounds.Bottom
        Row(0)("y2") = sender.Bounds.Top
        'Collision check
        Dim CollidedRows() As DataRow = MovingControls.Select("(" & sender.Bounds.Right & " >= x1)" &
                                                              "AND (" & sender.Bounds.Left & " <= x2)" &
                                                              "AND (" & sender.Bounds.Bottom & " <= y2)" &
                                                              "AND (" & sender.Bounds.Top & " >= y1)" &
                                                              "AND (Name <> '" & sender.Name & "'")
        'Determine the object type and execute necessary code
        For Each CollidedRow As DataRow In CollidedRows
            Dim CollidedControl As Control = Me.Controls.Item(CollidedRow("Name"))
            If CollidedControl.GetType = GetType(Label) Then
                'Do stuff for labels
            ElseIf CollidedControl.GetType = GetType(Button) Then
                'Do stuff for buttons
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Caveat: This assumes 1 control is moving at a time. If Control A moves into Control B but Control B moves away at the same time, this code will still call a collision even though the collision was avoided. If you have multiple controls moving, you may want to split the MovingControlMoved method into 2 methods, one for updating the table and one for collision checks. Handle all movement first, then handle all collisions.

Depending on the complexity, you may want to create custom classes for collidable controls that inherit an interface for collisions. You can use System.Reflection to call RunMeOnCollision. This would eliminate the list of If statements.

```
Interface iCollidableBase
    Sub RunMeOnCollision()
End Interface

Public Class CollidableLabel
    Inherits Label
    Implements iCollidableBase

    Public Sub RunMeOnCollision() Implements iCollidableBase.RunMeOnCollision
        Me.Text = "I have been collided"
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class CollidableButton
    Inherits Button
    Implements iCollidableBase

    Public Sub RunMeOnCollision() Implements iCollidableBase.RunMeOnCollision
        Me.Text = "Ouch, that collision hurt!"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Again, not knowing the full context here, I can't test my solution against your code. If you can post some additional details, I might be able to help more.

-E

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply - I will be sure to go through it a few times. The second solution looks interesting, and it might be what I'm looking for. I will update the question with the code from my form.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I needed from my programming teacher, using arrays.

In the public sub:
`Dim walls(17) As PictureBox`
Where 17 is the number of (In this case) boundaries that your form has. Also change PictureBox to the object you are using (for example labels).
Then in your form load:

```
 For i = 1 To 17
        walls(i) = Me.Controls("boundary" & i)
    Next
```

I'm honestly not 100% sure about this, but the "boundary" string is a section of the name of my PictureBoxes, that are acting as boundaries. There names are boundary1, boundary2, etc. So you might change "boundary" to what your object's names are.

Next, when you want to check for something using the boundaries, declare

```
 For i = 1 To 17
```

Then when you want to close checking for it,

```
Next
```

For the checking of collisions, use this:

```
If object.Bounds.IntersectsWith(walls(i).Bounds) Then
```

So in this case, the If statement would go between the For and Next lines.